# Why most of the tokens on BSC have the IERC20 interface implemented and not the BEP20 interface?

Tags: erc-20

I am getting started in solidity and this confuses me. I managed to deploy some tokens using BEP20 interface on the BSC testnet and it worked fine, but as I see, most of the tokens use IERC20 interface. I tried to deploy a token with the IERC20 interface and I couldn't interact with it's functions in bscscan.

Can anybody explain me this? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

For the most part, they are the same thing.

The only differences is that BEP20 adds `getOwner`, `name`, and `symbol` methods, and `Transfer` event, i.e. BEP20 implements everything that IERC20 interface requires, but vice-versa is not true.

As to why, well, no one is stopping you to upload any contract. You only need BEP20 if you want to be compatible with other contracts that require BEP20.